How to have Moto Tag be listed in Find My Device?
I bought a Motorola Moto Tag.
I can pair the tag, I can see it in the companion Moto Tag app. Here, I can let the Moto Tag ring.
Yet if I follow the button to find my device on the map, I see Google's Find My Device, yet my Moto Tag is not listed.
If lookup my Moto Tag via the bluetooth settings, and Find Devive, I get a view stating that my Moto Tag is not connected.
What am I missing? How to add Moto Tag to Find my Device, so that I can view it on the map?

I think I located the issue by the Moto Tag not realyzing that the Find My Device has been enabled. It asks to enable the Find My Device, yet it never continues.
All I can do is cancel or swipe the menu away:
Prompt

Enabling the Option

Yet not found in Find My Device, asking again to enable:


I am using a One Plus 9 Pro having Android 14 (October 2024).
I could update the Moto Tag to firmware 2.0.35 (it had 2.0.19), yet issue persists.
I tried resetting the Moto Tag via one-tap, quickly followed by an at least 5 second tap while holding until it beeps. Yet on reconnect, the issue remains.

Related: https://support.google.com/android/thread/295299000/moto-tag-not-visible-on-my-find-my-device-on-browser?hl=en

Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/1fv4cow/problem_moto_tag_does_not_appear_under
